# (int num) fix parse int from xpath and split

Tags: c#, xpath, console-application

My values can't sparse in any way, I keep getting an error

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Index was outside the bounds of the array.".

i try:

```
var result= int.Parse(
                            (await (await elresult.GetPropertyAsync("textContent")).JsonValueAsync())
                            .ToString()
                            .Split(":")[1]);
                        // IF time 0
                        if (result == 0)
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(2000);
                            // Get element
                            elresult = video ?
                                await page.WaitForXPathAsync(@"//*[@id=""root""]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/span", waitOptions) : // Stream
                                await page.WaitForXPathAsync(@"//*[@id=""root""]/div/div[2]/div/main/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/span", waitOptions); // Video
                            // Get time
                            result = int.Parse(
                                (await (await elresult.GetPropertyAsync("textContent")).JsonValueAsync())
                                .ToString()
                                .Split(":")[1]);
                            // If time = 0
                            if (result == 0) { result = 20; }
                        }
```

Everytime i have a 0:27 or 0:22 or 0:12, and i must get only 27 or 22 or 12, remove 0: from parse text. Can i fix it?

Comment: Hard to guess, without data. Also, this is wirtten so complicated and confusing, that, if you right now do not know how it works, you want be able to maintain it in ... maybe 2 weeks from now? [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) ;)

Comment: Given that `something = "0:27"` then `something.Split(":")[1]` will return `"27"` like you want. The values returned from `WaitForXPathAsync` and `JsonValueAsync` must be something different from what you're expecting. Try breaking down those big statements which are doing too much at once into multiple smaller statements. You should then be able to debug the application and see what `WaitForXPathAsync` and `JsonValueAsync` are actually returning.

Answer (score 0):

If you always need to remove **"0:"** you can use `Replace()` method instead of `Split()`

Try something like this:

```
var result = int.Parse((await (await elresult.GetPropertyAsync("textContent")).JsonValueAsync()).ToString().Replace("0:", ""));
// IF time 0
if (result == 0)
{
  await Task.Delay(2000);
  // Get element
  elresult = video ?
      await page.WaitForXPathAsync(@"//*[@id=""root""]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/span", waitOptions) : // Stream
      await page.WaitForXPathAsync(@"//*[@id=""root""]/div/div[2]/div/main/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/span", waitOptions); // Video
                                                                                                                                                                         // Get time
  result = int.Parse((await (await elresult.GetPropertyAsync("textContent")).JsonValueAsync()).ToString().Replace("0:", ""));
  // If time = 0
  if (result == 0) { result = 20; }
}
```